# Filtering only the value of 'download_url' from the following output - python

Tags: python, regex

Kindly help me filter the value. I tried with re but doesnt help. Thanks!

```
{"total_count":1,"entries":[{"type":"file","id":"51371323013","file_version":{"type":"file_version","id":"52926277625","sha1":"22596363b3de40b06f981fb85d82312e8c0ed511"},"sequence_id":"1","etag":"1","sha1":"22596363b3de40b06f981fb85d82312e8c0ed511","name":"hello.txt","description":"","size":12,"path_collection":{"total_count":1,"entries":[{"type":"folder","id":"0","sequence_id":null,"etag":null,"name":"All Files"}]},"created_at":"2016-01-28T23:02:21-08:00","modified_at":"2016-01-28T23:02:21-08:00","trashed_at":null,"purged_at":null,"content_created_at":"2016-01-28T23:01:42-08:00","content_modified_at":"2016-01-28T23:01:42-08:00","created_by":{"type":"user","id":"262253433","name":"RZF-ICA","login":"blah@blah.com"},"modified_by":{"type":"user","id":"262253433","name":"RZF-ICA","login":"blah@blah.com"},"owned_by":{"type":"user","id":"262253433","name":"RZF-ICA","login":"blah@blah.com"},"shared_link":{"url":"https:\/\/app.box.com\/s\/84wqj8mvwm77ern12121mbe4b68lgf","download_url":"https:\/\/app.box.com\/shared\/static\/84wqj8mvwm77ernjtkvm131b68lgf.txt","vanity_url":null,"effective_access":"company","is_password_enabled":false,"unshared_at":null,"download_count":0,"preview_count":0,"access":"company","permissions":{"can_download":true,"can_preview":true}},"parent":{"type":"folder","id":"0","sequence_id":null,"etag":null,"name":"All Files"},"item_status":"active"}],"limit":1,"offset":0}
```

Comment: This should work: `re.search(r'"download_url":"(.+?)"', output).group(1)`

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer @tjohnson

Comment: The error message is saying that the second argument you pass to the re.search function needs to be a string.

Comment: @tjohnson i converted my output to string using str(). But now i get another error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: This is because if the regex doesn't find anything, the re.search function returns None. You'll need to check the value that it returns and only call the group() function if it matches something. If the string is not always formatted consistently, it would be better to use the json module as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex. Use a json parser. It will parse the json into a nested python dictionary. This is much more robust than using regular expressions.

```
import json
data = json.loads(your_input_json_string)
print(data['entries'][0]['shared_link']['download_url'])
```

If you use a regular expression you are likely to end up with a bug when you get an input url containing a `"` character. This is a valid url:

`https://www.google.com/?q="when+not+to+use+regular+expressions"`